# How to use payment gateway POST webhook data in PHP

Tags: php, instamojo

I am making a payment gateway of instamojo, i am done payment making option i dont know how to handle Webhook after payment:

A sample POST webhook data will look something like this:

```
{
 'amount': '2500.00',
 'buyer': 'foo@example.com',
 'buyer_name': 'John Doe',
 'buyer_phone': '9999999999',
 'currency': 'INR',
 'fees': '125.00',
 'longurl': 'https://www.instamojo.com/@dalan/264a89803cec4401862f01e28f720eca',
 'mac': '1ddf3b78f84d071324c0bf1d3f095898267d60ee',
 'payment_id': 'MOJO5a06005J21512197',
 'payment_request_id': '264a89803cec4401862f01e28f720eca',
 'purpose': 'FIFA 16',
 'shorturl': 'https://imjo.in/NNNXn',
 'status': 'Credit'
}
```

Note that the webhook request’s content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded.`

Please give me any example.

I have tried to receive as below but not working

```
$data = $_POST;
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

But its not working, so please help me.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? What have you done to troubleshoot? What is the value of `$_POST`? What is the value of `$data`?

Comment: i am getting in below data in $_POST {
 'amount': '2500.00',
 'buyer': 'foo@example.com',
 'buyer_name': 'John Doe',
 'buyer_phone': '9999999999',
 'currency': 'INR',
 'fees': '125.00',
 'longurl': 'https://www.instamojo.com/@dalan/264a89803cec4401862f01e28f720eca',
 'mac': '1ddf3b78f84d071324c0bf1d3f095898267d60ee',
 'payment_id': 'MOJO5a06005J21512197',
 'payment_request_id': '264a89803cec4401862f01e28f720eca',
 'purpose': 'FIFA 16',
 'shorturl': 'https://imjo.in/NNNXn',
 'status': 'Credit'
}

Comment: That does not appear to be valid JSON, due to the single quotes. See the ["bad json" examples at php.net's `json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-4303). Try [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.